# How to access drl files in to hadoop distibuted cache?

Tags: java, hadoop, drools

I did a drools program in eclipse 3.8

I have 2 drools files.

I want to share my Drools files to all mappers and reducers. So how it can be done using hadoop distributed cache ? Before that should files exist at local files system or HDFS.

Here is the program that how Drools files can be accessed into program without distributed cache. See it and give me clarity for storing drools into distributed cache and the way to access that files in program.

```
public class JUnitTests {

@Test
public void testMapReduceJob1() throws Exception {
    String drlDir = "/Users/mbp_user/devel/java/drools-hadoop/drl/";
    String hdfsOut = "output";
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    fs.delete(new Path(hdfsOut), true);

    MapReduceByStateless.main(new String[] {
            "-files",
            drlDir + "rule1.drl",
            "input",
            "output"
            }
    );
}

@Test
public void testMapReduceJob2() throws Exception {
    String drlDir = "/Users/mbp_user/devel/java/drools-hadoop/drl/";
    String hdfsOut = "output";
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    fs.delete(new Path(hdfsOut), true);

    MapReduceByStateful.main(new String[] {
            "-files",
            drlDir + "rule2.drl",
            "input",
            "output"
            }
    );
}
}
```

Comment: This is hardly a Drools problem. In main, the 2nd argument is a String that's a pathname to a file: any valid pathname should work. - What happens in `MapReduceByStateful.main`?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  int ret = ToolRunner.run(new MapReduceByStateful(), args);
  System.exit(ret);
 }

Comment: Very funny. What happens in ToolRunner.run, especially with `args[1]`?